# Sorting a class array in Java?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I'm making a number guessing game for a school project in Java, which I'm extremely bad at. I've got everything to work with classes and the guessing part, but now I'm going to create a top players list and sort it and I have no idea how.
This is the code I use for guessing and creating objects of the player.

```
public static void spela() {
        int nummer= ((int) (1+Math.random()*100));
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner s_input = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean ratt = false;
        int forsok = 1;
        int gissning;
        String namn;
        while(ratt==false) {
            System.out.println("Gissa nummer: ");
            gissning = input.nextInt();
            if(gissning == nummer) {
                System.out.println("Grattis du gissade rätt! Tog: " + forsok + " försök att gissa rätt!");
                System.out.println("Skriv in namn: ");
                namn = s_input.nextLine();
                for(int i=0;i<cr;i++) {
                    if(namn.equals(allaspelare[i].namn)) {
                        allaspelare[i].setpoang(forsok);
                        ratt=true;
                        menu();
                    }
                }

                allaspelare[cr] = new spelare(namn);
                allaspelare[cr].setpoang(forsok);
                cr++;
                ratt=true;

                menu();
            }
            if(gissning > nummer) {
                System.out.println("Du gissade: " + gissning + " och det var för mycket!");
            }
            if(gissning < nummer) {
                System.out.println("Du gissade: " + gissning + " och det var för lite!");
            }
            forsok++;
        }

    }
```

this is the "spelare" class:

```
public class spelare {
    int[] poang = new int[100];
    int antal;
    String namn;
    public spelare(String innamn) {
        namn = innamn;
    }
    public void setpoang(int inpoang) {
        poang[antal] = inpoang;
        antal++;
    }
}
```

as you see one player can have multiple scores so that's the problem I can't get it right in my mind how I'm going to sort it so the output if I wan't to get out the score chart will come like:

```
testplayer1: 9
testplayer2: 11
testplayer3: 34
```

So basically I need help to code a method that goes through the class and sort it and output it as above! Any help/sources is extremely appreciated!
And commented code would be extremely appreciated so I can learn!

EDIT:
I've been searching for hours, and the only thing that I found was this:

```
public static void sortera(int[] lista, int plats) {
    int i;
    if (lista.length < 2) return;
    int temp;

    for(int n=1; n<lista.length; n++) {
        temp=lista[n];
        i = n - 1;
        while(i >=0 && lista[i] > temp) {
            lista[i+1] = lista[i];
        } 
        lista[i+1] = temp;
    }
    allaspelare[plats].poang = lista;
}
```

And this is how I called it:

```
case 5:
                sortera(allaspelare[0].poang, 0);
break;
```

but this doesn't do anything..

Comment: There are lots of examples of sorting algorithms online.  What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

The structure you use is simply bad. Instead you should use pairs of names and scores. This way multiple scorepairs with the same name exist, but you can easily sort them.

```
public class Score implements Comparable<Score>{
     private int score;
     private String name;

     public Score(String name , int score){
          this.score = score;
          this.name = name;
     }

     //getters and setters as required

     public int compareTo(Score s){
          return score - s.score;
     }
}
```

This aswell allows you to directly compare `Score`objects to eachother. This way a list of `Score` objects can easily be sorted via `Collections.sort(someList)`.

Comment: Could you give me an example? Because I'm totally stuck and I have no idea how to continue, I've been searching for sorting algorithms etc but I can't find anything that works..

Comment: Thank you extremely much, but the problem is that I need to code the sort method myself and can't use .sort, otherwise it'd be super easy!

Comment: you could try bubblesort (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort). rather "ugly" and not exactly efficient, but it's easy to implement.